# calling payable (solidity) method with python

Tags: contract-development

I want to send two Ether from my node to my `invest()` method in the contract. But I don't know how to do it with python.

Solidity:

```
function invest() payable { 

    value = msg.value / 1000000000000000000;
    counter += value;
    if(value >0 && value < 3){
         lastdonation = msg.sender;
        if(counter  % 5 == 0){
            winner = msg.sender;
            winnerbool =true;
            message = "congratulation you won 3 Ether";
            //if he wins he will get the 3 Ether; 
            winner.send(msg.value);

        }else{
            bank.send(msg.value);
            winnerbool= false;
            message = "No luck. Try it again";
        }
           }
        else{
           message = "Transaktion not possible. it is just possible to input 
integer ether of one or two.";
        }
    }
```

I have already an instance of the contract. It works fine. But how can I now call my invest() method which is payable and give two ether to the contract?

Python:

```
def clean1():
    button1.config(text="Send 1 Ether")
    fContract.invest({from: "0x3eC35e7525cDd47c76da8D8BcAA945a64e55096B", 
value= "1000000000000000"})
    if fContract.functions.Winner().call():
        window.after(10, winner)
    else:
        window.after(10, lose)

button1 = Button(window, text="Send 1 Ether",bg="DodgerBlue4", fg="white", 
command=readone)
button1.grid(row=2, column=0)
button1.config(height = 4 , width = 23 )
```

I want to make the same like Ethereum Wallet (Mist) is doing. Sending 2 Ether to the invest() method.

Ethereum Wallet Mist

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please paste the actual code into your question, rather than a screenshot, and formatting using the code formatting button in the editor. Having the actual code makes it easier to search and read.

Answer (score 0):

Using web3py you can access the functions in your contract, which I assume is what you are doing. From your code, I get that the contract instance is `fcontract`.

You can do:

```
fcontract.functions.invest().transact({'from':'you account address','value': web3.toWei(2,'ether')})
```

Note: Remember to unlock your account before executing the line above.

Hope this helps